# SQL recursively filter results to exclude 3 most recent records for each matching field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have data where records will share a common `parent` value. I'd like to return all records expect for the most recent 3 records for each `parent`.

For example, my data looks something like this to start:

```
----------------------------------------------
| ID     | post_date           | post_parent |
----------------------------------------------
| 326524 | 2018-08-17 14:48:09 |        1576 |
| 326693 | 2018-08-18 12:49:10 |        1576 |
| 326694 | 2018-08-18 13:04:21 |        1576 |
| 326695 | 2018-08-18 13:05:02 |        1576 |
| 326749 | 2018-08-19 19:30:33 |        1576 |
| 326752 | 2018-08-19 19:39:43 |        1576 |
| 19340  | 2011-05-28 10:38:46 |       19323 |
| 19344  | 2011-05-28 10:40:10 |       19323 |
| 19345  | 2011-05-28 10:42:12 |       19323 |
| 19347  | 2011-05-28 10:45:53 |       19323 |
| 19349  | 2011-05-28 10:49:53 |       19323 |
| 19350  | 2011-05-28 10:52:40 |       19323 |
| 19351  | 2011-05-28 10:55:45 |       19323 |
| 19352  | 2011-05-28 10:55:58 |       19323 |
| 19353  | 2011-05-28 10:57:46 |       19323 |
| 161381 | 2016-10-26 10:53:52 |       19323 |
| 161417 | 2016-10-26 12:15:56 |       19323 |
| 161418 | 2016-10-26 12:16:31 |       19323 |
| 163912 | 2016-11-10 14:24:11 |       19323 |
| 163914 | 2016-11-10 14:28:24 |       19323 |
| 163954 | 2016-11-10 16:35:51 |       19323 |
| 163956 | 2016-11-10 16:39:54 |       19323 |
| 163959 | 2016-11-10 16:43:32 |       19323 |
| 321095 | 2018-07-29 10:44:54 |       19323 |
| 321097 | 2018-07-27 17:28:09 |       19323 |
| 321135 | 2018-07-29 10:45:59 |       19323 |
| 321136 | 2018-07-29 10:57:00 |       19323 |
----------------------------------------------
```

I'd like to end up with:

```
----------------------------------------------
| ID     | post_date           | post_parent |
----------------------------------------------
| 326524 | 2018-08-17 14:48:09 |       1576  |
| 326693 | 2018-08-18 12:49:10 |       1576  |
| 326694 | 2018-08-18 13:04:21 |       1576  |
| 19340  | 2011-05-28 10:38:46 |      19323  |
| 19344  | 2011-05-28 10:40:10 |      19323  |
| 19345  | 2011-05-28 10:42:12 |      19323  |
| 19347  | 2011-05-28 10:45:53 |      19323  |
| 19349  | 2011-05-28 10:49:53 |      19323  |
| 19350  | 2011-05-28 10:52:40 |      19323  |
| 19351  | 2011-05-28 10:55:45 |      19323  |
| 19352  | 2011-05-28 10:55:58 |      19323  |
| 19353  | 2011-05-28 10:57:46 |      19323  |
| 161381 | 2016-10-26 10:53:52 |      19323  |
| 161417 | 2016-10-26 12:15:56 |      19323  |
| 161418 | 2016-10-26 12:16:31 |      19323  |
| 163912 | 2016-11-10 14:24:11 |      19323  |
| 163914 | 2016-11-10 14:28:24 |      19323  |
| 163954 | 2016-11-10 16:35:51 |      19323  |
| 163956 | 2016-11-10 16:39:54 |      19323  |
| 163959 | 2016-11-10 16:43:32 |      19323  |
| 321097 | 2018-07-27 17:28:09 |      19323  |
----------------------------------------------
```

I initially tried something like

sql

```
select a.post_type
     , a.ID
     , a.post_parent
     , a.post_date
     , b.ID as parent_id
     , b.post_type as parent_post_type
     , b.post_status as parent_status 
  from wp_posts a 
  join wp_posts b 
 where a.post_type = 'revision' 
   and a.post_date > '2018-03-20' 
   and a.post_parent = b.id 
   and b.post_status = 'publish' 
   AND a.post_parent NOT IN (select post_parent 
                               from wp_posts 
                              where post_parent = 1576 
                                and post_type = 'revision' 
                              ORDER 
                                 BY post_date DESC 
                              LIMIT 3)
```

But realized 2 problems:

1. `LIMIT` is not supported in an `IN` clause
2. Even if it was, the LIMIT in my query would only return 3 posts
   total, rather than 3 for each post parent.

I'm assuming the next step would be to break this into a php loop and execute there, but I'm curious if I could pull this off in SQL!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a subquery . . . but not using `in`:

```
select pr.post_type, pr.ID, pr.post_parent, pr.post_date,
       pp.ID as parent_id, pp.post_type as parent_post_type, pp.post_status as parent_status 
from wp_posts pr inner join
     wp_posts pp 
     on pr.post_parent = pp.id 
where pr.post_type = 'revision' and apr.post_date > '2018-03-20' and 
      pp.post_status = 'publish' and
      pr.post_date <= coalesce( (select p2.post_date
                                 from wp_posts
                                 where p2.post_parent = pr.post_parent and
                                       p2.post_type = 'revision' 
                                 order by p2.post_date desc
                                 limit 1, 2
                                ), pr.post_date
                               );
```

The key idea is that you can use a scalar subquery with `<`.  I think I fixed the query to do what you want, as well as introducing reasonable table aliases.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a window function. This works in [MySQL v8.0](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/565uVmUaGmRrnh8yDiJPQi/0), but maybe not in earlier version.

```
with temp as (
    select 
        ID,
        post_date,
        post_parent,
        row_number() over (partition by post_parent order by post_date desc) rankno
    from table_name
)

select *
from temp
where rankno > 3;
```